# ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected(Truffle test)

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am currently learning solidity.

I have written the code as it appears in "Hands-On Smart Contract Development With Solidity and Ethereum" (O'Reilly/Japanese edition), but when I run TruffleTest, I get the following error

CompileError: project:/contracts/Fundraiser.sol:9:1: ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.

Here is the code.

https://github.com/okahijiki/fundraiser

I would appreciate any advice you can give me.

My library's version

Truffle
v5.5.31 (core: 5.5.31)/
Ganache v7.4.3/
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)/
Node v16.15.1/
Web3.js v1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Here's the linked code:

```
pragma solidity >0.4.23 <0.7.0;

contract Fundraiser{
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory _name)public{
        name = _name;
}
```

Count the number of opening braces - and the number of closing braces. You are correctly opening and closing the `contract`, but the `constructor` is missing its closing brace.

The solution is simple - close the `constructor` block with a brace as well.

```
contract Fundraiser{
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory _name)public{
        name = _name;
    } // closing the constructor here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.　　　
I have tried closing the constructor block as you suggested. However, I get the following error.　　

throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources");　　


The Truffle test can be viewed on YouTube below.　　　　　
　　

[https://youtu.be/8AXnH9vy68Q](https://youtu.be/8AXnH9vy68Q)